# DBUS interface to decrypt a LUKS device?

Tags: d-bus, dm-crypt

In modern DEs, like KDE or XFCE, you can mount a LUKS device after entering the password.

Now I want to do this without the file manager, with two steps,

1. Decrypt the device
2. Mount the disk with `udisks` command

For the first step, there should be a dbus interface involved, any ideas?
Or correct me on how the file managers do that without root permission ...

(P.S I'm not asking for a `sudo` solution, although I could do that, but I prefer a dbus solution)

Comment: With `udisks` see http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/1.0.5/Device.html#Device.LuksUnlock - jftr you can play around with dbus via `qdbus`

Comment: `udisks` als has support for this. `udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sda`

Comment: @t-8ch ah cool, I only read about `udisks`, not `udisksctl`

Comment: `udisksctl` is from `udisks2`

Comment: @t-8ch ah that works, what about the command for "luksClose"?

Comment: `udisksctl lock -b /dev/sda` should do the trick